# An Issue Updating a Table in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to update a table in MySQL, using PHP.

Some rows have the same index value, column name is 'num'.

I have an array of numbers to update into a column called 'code'.

[Illustration of the Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrGTV.png)

Lets call this array $codearr: [100,200,400,300,500,900,1500,150,50,20,1000].

I want to insert the numbers from the list one-by-one, line-by-line, where 'num' equals 1, by using UPDATE command.

All my efforts did not insert the list as it was ordered, like in my example, skewing the order of the list.

My efforts:

I tried to add a unique identifier to each row by creating a new column naming it 'uniq' and putting a random number there.

After that I retrieved the list of values of the column 'uniq', and the column 'num', and put them in separate arrays.
I have created a loop of inserting the numbers from the $codearr to column 'code', by going through the array of values from 'uniq' and per each unique identifier inserted a number from my list.

I do not know why my loop is inserting the numbers from the list not by the correct order and would appreciate some assistance.

```
$codearr=[100,200,400,300,500,900,1500,150,50,20,1000];

$i=0;
while($i<count($codearr))
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE test SET code = ? WHERE num = 1 AND uniq = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $codearr[$i], $uniq[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $i++;
}
```

Assuming $uniq array has all the unique identifiers.
The intent is to insert as preordered in $codearr.

Comment: Use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `uniq` column.

Comment: What is `$uniq`?  What's in it?  Can you not make a single trip to the db and use a `CASE` statement in the SET clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop in PHP that updates just one row where `num` is empty, by using `LIMIT 1` in the `UPDATE` statement.

```
$codearr = [100,200,400,300,500,900,1500,150,50,20,1000];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    UPDATE yourTable 
    SET code = ?
    WHERE num = 1 AND code IS NULL 
    LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $code);
foreach ($codearr as $code) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Each iteration will pick one of the unfilled rows arbitrarily and update it.

Comment: Will try that method of using LIMIT 1. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use mysqli syntax instead of PDO.

Comment: Worked, however I found a different way. Thanks anyway.